# How to subprocess the files on console directly (with or without using StringIO)?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, stringio

I am trying to read a gtf file and then edit it (using subprocess, grep and awk) before loading into pandas.

I have a file name that has header info (indicated by `#`), so I need to grep that and remove it first. I can do it in python but I want to introduce `grep` into my pipeline to make processing more efficient.

**I tried doing:**

```
import subprocess
from io import StringIO

gtf_file = open('chr2_only.gtf', 'r').read()
gtf_update = subprocess.Popen(["grep '^#' " + StringIO(gtf_file)], shell=True)
```

**and**

```
gtf_update = subprocess.Popen(["grep '^#' " + gtf_file], shell=True)
```

Both of these codes throw an error, for the 1st attempt it was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/everestial007/PycharmProjects/stitcher/pHASE-Stitcher-Markov/markov_final_test/phase_to_vcf.py", line 39, in <module> gtf_update = subprocess.Popen(["grep '^#' " + StringIO(gtf_file)], shell=True)
TypeError: Can't convert '_io.StringIO' object to str implicitly
```

However, if I specify the filename directly it works:

```
gtf_update = subprocess.Popen(["grep '^#' chr2_only.gtf"], shell=True)
```

and the output is:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fc12e5ea588>
#!genome-build v.1.0
#!genome-version JGI8X
#!genome-date 2008-12
#!genome-build-accession GCA_000004255.1
#!genebuild-last-updated 2008-12
```

**Could someone please provide different examples for problem like this, and also explain why am I getting the error and why/how it would be possible to run subprocess directly on files loaded on console/memory?**

I also tried using `subprocess` with `call, check_call, check_output, etc.`, but I've gotten several different error messages, like these:

```
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long
```

and

```
Subprocess in Python: File Name too long
```

Comment: I've seen "Subprocess in Python: File Name too long" before. This happened to me when I was unintentionally passing the text within an open file as an argument to Popen instead of a string for the filename path. When you assign `gtf_update = subprocess.Popen(["grep '^#' chr2_only.gtf"], shell=True)`, you can then output that command using `gtf_update.communicate()`

Comment: In your `grep` command, you have to pass the *filename*, as you do in your working example. In the first ones, you try to add a StringIO object or a file object to the string `"grep '^#' "`, and Python can't convert them to a string. Just append the filename instead.

Comment: But, I don't want to read the file name on the `subprocess`. The reason being I have to use this file for different branches of the pipeline. So, I want to read it in a pythonic way `data = open(....).read()', then use this `data` to do different things. Just trying to save memory and time by not reading the same files over and over again.

Comment: If you read the file's lines into Python eventually, you likely have nothing to win by using an external `grep` over trivial `if not line.startswith('#')` Python code. If you have a non-trivial pipeline with `grep` and `awk`, write a shell script and make it work first (with `awk` you don' need `grep`). If `grep` eliminated most of the input lines in a non-trivial way, it could benefit performance. Is it so in your case? Try avoiding premature optimization, that is, optimization prior to actually (not theoretically) detecting a bottleneck.

Comment: Hmm, something to think about ! I am trying different things. Lets see how `awk` responds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that allows you to send a string to grep. Essentially, you declare in the `Popen` constructor that you want to communicate with the called program via stdin and stdout. You then send the input via communicate and receive the output as return value from communicate.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

gtf_file = open('chr2_only.gtf', 'r').read()
gtf_update = subprocess.Popen(["grep '^#' "], shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# stdout, stderr (but latter is empty)
gtf_filtered, _ = gtf_update.communicate(gtf_file)

print gtf_filtered
```

Note that it is wise not to use `shell=True`. Therefore, the Popen line should be written as

```
gtf_update = subprocess.Popen(["grep", '^#'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The rationale is that you don't need the shell to parse the arguments to a single executable. So you avoid unnecessary overhead. It is also better from a security point of view, at least if some argument is potentially unsafe  as it comes from a user (think of a filename containing `|`). (This is obviously not the case here.)

Note that from a performance point of view, I expect that reading the file directly with `grep` is faster than first reading the file with python, and then sending it to grep.